# How to mesh two pictures together

Tags: html, css, html-table, formatting

I did ask a similar question not too long ago, but I found some new information on the topic and I think that I can explain a bit better now.

I have two puzzle pieces, both are transparent .pngs (except the actual pieces):

[image: To see these pieces, here's a link:]
[image: http://imgur.com/a/6vsNa#UPYw2i4]

Here's the code that I'm using to display my two pieces right now -

```
<body>
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaQXq.png">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/reU70.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The images are beside each other, but not interlocking like they should. I know that this is supposed to happen, because who wants overlapping pictures. So my question is, how do I have them overlap?

The puzzle isn't meant to be built, it's meant to be pre-built and the pieces appear at different times using opacity, if that makes any sense.

Any direction would be awesome, as I'm new to this (having a blast learning though).

Comment: Just to update, jsfiddle was experiencing a DDOS attack and was therefore in read-only mode. You should be able to save now.
https://twitter.com/jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a "fancier" solution using the Jquery UI draggable widget:

http://plnkr.co/edit/BYDyqjBLUOXFcuPvqWvx?p=preview

html

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title><!-- Title here --></title>
<link data-require="jqueryui" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="jqueryui" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/UPYw2i4.png" class="draggable">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/7rkQ0hz.png" class="draggable">
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
//js
$(function(){
  $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

This allows you to grab and move each piece with the mouse. Had to use plnkr...because like you, i could not figure out for the life of me how to save a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce the desired result with some CSS Magic

```
<body>
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UPYw2i4.png">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/7rkQ0hz.png" class="merge">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.merge
{
    position:relative;
    right:92px;
    top:4px;
}
```

Comment: Looks really good, thanks! Now if I wanted to complete the puzzle using this method, I would just add more images and css classes?

Comment: Yeah it will be hard to come up with a generic class to cover all connection possibilities, but maybe you can add an x/y pixel coordinate to each picture that specifies the center of the "connectors". Then you could just align the coordinates on top of eachother to make them connect. This is a cool problem to figure out how to make generic, i would be interested in the result.

Comment: Yeah that would be a nifty block of code. You could use that for a lot of things. I'll let you know if I ever figure it out haha

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with a tableset.  The columns won't overlap properly.  Even if you could pull it off, you can't expect it to work across all browsers.

You could easily accomplish this with DIVs and CSS.  There you have complete control over placement.